# Codeception radio button list

Tags: yii2, radiobuttonlist, codeception

I've got a radio button list in the form of

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" style="margin: 5px 0 20px">
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="0"> 0</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="1"> 1</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="2"> 2</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="3"> 3</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="4"> 4</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="5"> 5</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="6"> 6</label>
     <label class="btn grey active"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="7" checked=""> 7</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="8"> 8</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="9"> 9</label>
     <label class="btn grey"><input type="radio" name="ResponseForm[nps]" value="10"> 10</label>
</div>
```

When I try to check if a radio is selected with

```
    ::canSeeOptionsIsSelected('form input[type=radio]', 1);
```

It is throwing an error:

```
 Step  I can see option is selected "form input[type=radio]",1
 Fail  Element located either by name, CSS or XPath element with 'selected option' was not found.
```

As I understand it is looking for a select tag, not a radio button. If it's not a proper way to check if a radio is selected, then what is?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector seems to be malformed since you don't use the `form` tag in your HTML file. Maybe try an xpath like: `//input[@type='radio']` in `canSeeOptionsIsSelected()` function

Comment: I just didn't paste it here.
The code works fine if I call ::amOnPage(); TWICE, which is weird.